# TypeError: Greedy[str] is invalid - Discord.py

Tags: python-3.x, discord.py

I am using an Inline Converters in Discord.py, which is Greedy ([It's Documentation](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ext/commands/api.html#discord.ext.commands.Greedy), [More Demo Code](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ext/commands/commands.html#greedy))

As you can see from those demo codes, It can also accept types like `int`, but when I use `str`, It raises this Error

```
TypeError: Greedy[str] is invalid
```

The command's code (By the way, it's a Cog command)

```py
@commands.command()
async def temp(self, ctx:commands.Context, message:commands.Greedy[str]='None', user:discord.Member=None):
    await ctx.send(f'{message = }, {user.mention}')
```

It's just a temporary command for now, but the `Greedy[str]` is not at all working, but it's working for `int`, `discord.Member` type values

And also I know about this too (The star parameter way)

```py
async def function_name(self, ctx, *, arg)
```

I know it does the same, but It only works only if I want it to pass all the rest of the parameter values to one variable as string, But I don't want this one, I want to pass the parameter values in the middle like this

```
temp temporary text @user
```

Because I want to implement this method to many commands later

Is there anyway to make it work?

And I am using Python v3.8.12, and Discord.py v1.7.3 in Replit

Edit: I am currently using this code for now as an alternative

```py
@commands.command()
async def temp(self, ctx: commands.Context, *arg):
    user_id = re.findall(r'(?<=<@)[!&]?(\d{17,22})(?=> *$)', arg[-1])
    if len(user_id ) == 0:
      raise TypeError('Command "temp" missing 1 required positional argument: "user"')
    user = ctx.guild.get_member(int(user_id[0]))
    message = ' '.join(arg[:-1])
    await ctx.send(f'{message = }, {user.mention}')
```

It'll be helpful if you've found a way to use Greedy converter

Answer (score 0):

This one of the way to  do but i guess there will be another way to solve this problem.

```py
@commands.command()
async def temp(self,ctx:commands.Context,*message):
  message=list(message)
  user=message[len(message)-1]
  message.pop()
  await ctx.send(message)
  await ctx.send(user)
```

After getting the value for user in this way you can check whether it is a member and then you can do your further code.

Comment: i actually have a better version of this, but i want to use the built-in feature, which i think using Greedy would make things easier

Comment: i've posted my temporary code for now in question, but still thanks for your answer

Comment: ok fine the probelm is ``commands.Greedy[str]`` is not supported actually which you are trying is equal to ``*args`` since every input that user is giving is string even discord.Member object which is also an string. So we can't use greedy function like you think.